# How to implement scheduler in Apex?

Tags: email, salesforce, scheduler, apex-code, visualforce

I see scheduler like feature in salesforce but it is somewhat tied with existing features that salesforce provide and no sample source code is provided as far as my research goes.

What I want to do is to create my own scheduler that sends simple email based on date.

**Goal:**

Custom Object `Player` has fields

```
startDate : date like '2010-11-01'
email : text field like foo@bar.com
name : player's name like John.
```

If today's date is one day before the startDate, I want to send email to the Player.
For instance, Player's name is `John` and if today is `2010-12-10` and one Player's `startDat`e is set to `2010-12-11`, email saying `"hello John"` is sent.

Unfortunately I cannot find good example or tutorial online or salesforce doc how to do this using Apex.
Could anyone point out where to get started?

**UPDATE**

I want to extend the answer from `eyescream.`

After setting scheduler, you can set what follow up action to take like sending email using template or set custom object fields to some values.

Below I found useful for people using email template in Visualforce format.

I have custom object 'alertTester' which has reference to other object 'custom' and even this object 'custom' has reference to another object 'custom1GrandChild' and all the relationship (up to 3 or 5 layers I think) can be accessed like below.

I've tested below and works fine. Now I'm receiving email with my condition set :)

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Hello" recipientType="User" relatedToType="alertTester__c" >
<messaging:plainTextEmailBody >

{!relatedTo.name}
{!relatedTo.custom__r.name}
{!relatedTo.custom__r.custom1GrandChild__r.name}


</messaging:plainTextEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out solutions that don't involve code before you'll dive deeply to Apex...

Email Alert + Workflow Rule should provide you with all functionality you need in this scenario and involve just clicking without any code.

Comment: I've looked at workflow page and found that only 5 email addresses can be setup. In my scenario, users will create schedule and Customer custom object has email field. So there would be 100 of customers each having individual email addresses. My Scheduler needs to look at each of them so this case might not fit into existing feature. Any thoughts?

Comment: Create Email Alert on Player object, set recipient type to "Email field". Your field (if it's type is really Email and not Text for example!) should appear on the list. Click the arrow to move it to right side of the screen. Hard to describe but maybe screenshot will help: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/709568/stackoverflow/masato%20email.png

Comment: Ok... Rule setting phase which is step 2/3 where you configure the condition, I choose date field of Player object for instance but actual value that salesforce accept is static date string such as '2001/10/10'.  <br /> What I need to do is like 'today() - 1 day' something like this but no luck..

Comment: Actually on the same page, I found the condition dropdown that make it "TRUE" which allows me to set condition in much more detail. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering to my own question again..

Below link, search for `schedule`

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index.htm

Looks like Apex has Schedulable interface that I can implements and set up cron task.

Below is sample code provided in the doc:

```
global class TestScheduledApexFromTestMethod implements Schedulable {

// This test runs a scheduled job at midnight Sept. 3rd. 2022  


   public static String CRON_EXP = '0 0 0 3 9 ? 2022';

   global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx) {
      CronTrigger ct = [SELECT id, CronExpression, TimesTriggered, NextFireTime
                FROM CronTrigger WHERE id = :ctx.getTriggerId()];

      System.assertEquals(CRON_EXP, ct.CronExpression);
      System.assertEquals(0, ct.TimesTriggered);
      System.assertEquals('2022-09-03 00:00:00', String.valueOf(ct.NextFireTime));

      Account a = [SELECT id, name FROM Account WHERE name = 
                  'testScheduledApexFromTestMethod'];
      a.name = 'testScheduledApexFromTestMethodUpdated';
      update a;
   }   
}
```

Comment: Hmm I've tried above but seems not working somehow. I set the scheduler to send myself email every hour but i'm not receiving.. still under investigation